# get selected value in knockoutJs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I passed values to `select data` by using below code

```
<select data-bind="options: preferedTimeToPickup,optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
    optionsText: 'name',value: preferedTimeToPickupVal" id="u3413_input" class="text_sketch">
</select>
```

In the KnockoutJs

```
this.preferedTimeToPickup = 
      [{name:"Specific: 8:00",price:10.25},
       {name:"Specific:9:00",price:12.25 },
       {name:"Specific: 10:00",price:13.25}
      ];
       this.preferedTimeToPickupVal = ko.observable();
```

When i try to get selected price while selecting  by using below code.

```
this.subtotal = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.preferedTimeToPickupVal().price;
});
```

Am getting below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preferedTimeToPickupVal' of undefined
```

Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: I am new to knockoutJs, i can not understand the mistake. please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your `computed` function you're referring to your view-model instance using the `this` keyword, you need to pass it the *function context* of the computed:

```
this.subtotal = ko.computed(function() {
    // now 'this' refers to your view-model, but you first
    // need to check if 'preferedTimeToPickupVal' is set
    var preferred = this.preferedTimeToPickupVal();

    if (preferred)
        return preferred.price;
    else
        return 0;
}, this);
```

Also, you need to check that `preferedTimeToPickupVal` is not empty before you're accessing its `price` property.

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#managing-this)

Comment: @ojeijr, appreciated  the answer, thank you so much.